# What are some of results in low dimensional statistics that do not hold in high dimensions?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, soft-question, st.statistics, measure-concentration

This question is partially inspired by the following MO post: [What are some of the surprising results of finite sample statistical estimation?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261643/what-are-some-of-the-surprising-results-of-finite-sample-statistical-estimation/262341#262341) and current heated research front of high dimensional statistics.

Instead of asking about surprising results in high dimensions, I will ask **what kind of results that holds in low dimensions fails to hold in a higher dimension. And what is its relation with other mathematical branch?**

(By *high dimensional statistics* we usually refer to a high dimension covariate space instead of response space. For example, in a regression setting $Y=f(X)$ we tend to say a problem is of high dimension if $\dim\mathcal{X}\gg \dim\mathcal{Y}$)

For one simplest example, we know that [James-Stein estimator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93745/james-stein-phenomenon-what-does-it-mean-that-a-james-stein-estimator-beats-lea/266937#266937) performs better than maximum likelihood estimator in terms of $L^2$ norm when the dimension $\dim\mathcal{X}=d\geq 3$; and it turns out to be an *equivalent statement* that a symmetric random walk in $\mathcal{X}=\mathbb{R}^d$ is transient when $d\geq 3$ via an infinitely divisible stochastic process. Another example is provided in the answer below.

Are there other such examples that can relate high dimensional phenomena in statistics?

Answer (score 3):

A great example that I have in mind is the concentration phenomena in high dimensions. Consider the simplest multivariate normal distribution $X\sim N_d(0_d,I_d)$, we can compute its $L^2$ norm $\sum_iX^2_i=:\|X\|^2\sim\chi^2(d)$. and $X_i^2\sim \chi^2(1)$ independently. With central limit theorem applied on each component, we have that $$\frac{1}{d}\sum^d_{i=1}X^2_i=\frac{1}{d}\|X\|^2\overset{P}{\rightarrow}N_1(1,\frac{2}{d})$$ as $d\rightarrow\infty$. Use the delta method we can see that $\|X\|\overset{P}{\rightarrow}\sqrt{d}N_1(1,\frac{1}{d})=N_1(\sqrt{d},1)$ and therefore we can actually assert that as dimension $d=dim\mathcal{X}\rightarrow \infty$ the random vectors are concentrated around a sphere.

Even more surprising is that if we have another independent $Y\sim N_d(0_d,I_d)$, then we can compute the distribution of $\frac{X\cdot Y}{\|X\|\|Y\|}$ as $d\rightarrow \infty$ is $N_1(0,d)$(multidimensional CLT and delta method) and the distribution of $\|X-Y\|$ as $d\rightarrow \infty$ is $N_1(0,2d)$. These two results claimed that as $d\rightarrow \infty$ two random vectors are most likely to be orthogonal and evenly distributed on the sphere, which is not expected when $d=1,2$.

I really hope to know if there are more such examples with a motivation from **consideration of the difference between the geometry of high and low dimensional spaces**.

Comment: I think you may have overstated the limiting variance of $\|X\|$, which I suspect is $\frac12$ rather than $1$, though it does not really affect your argument.  It means for example that over $99.5\%$ of the probability is concentrated in the band $\sqrt{d}\pm 2$ for $d>3$ and this is your "concentrated around a sphere".  This is not true for $d=1,2,3$ as $\sqrt{d}$ is not the best estimate of the centre of the distribution for small $d$; even for those small $d$ you have a high(er) concentration in a band of the same width such as $2 \pm2$